# how does scipy.misc.toimage changes image domain?

Tags: python

there's a code that I've been working on and I saw a code that I don't Understand, I really appreciate someone explains it to me how it works.

the first code will normalize it in [0,1] but in the third code, it makes it in e.g [2,89] (it depends on input image), 
1- my question is on code 3, how it makes it to the new domain? 
2- if I want to take it back on [0,255] how to undo code 3 (e.g I normalized it and then take it back to the first image)?

```
img = img.astype(np.float32)/255.0
sc = np.power(np.power(2.0, -3), 0.5)
img=scipy.misc.toimage(sc*np.squeeze(img), cmin=0.0, cmax=1.0)
img=np.asarray(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally after a few days I figured it out, I Answer it here in case someone had my answer :)

it works like scipy.misc.bytescale and the math behind that is like below:

```
((I-Cmin)/(Cmax-Cmin))*255
```

the I parameter is the value of the pixel. for the test, you should make a small matrix like (e.g 3 by 3) and change the Cmax and Cmin. I'm sure you'll understand better.